# replace string between characters

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace numbers between the first and second period with new text.

```
old <- c("test_test.123.test.test", "something.456.something")
```

For instance, let's say I want `old` to become:

```
"test_test.000.test.test" "something.111.something"
```

I'm trying learn how to grep the pattern. I thought it might be something like:

```
grep("^[:punct:][[:digit:]]+[:punct:]$", old)
```

...but no luck. Once I get this working, I can look up the replacement in `key`:

```
key <- data.frame(old=c("123", "456"),
                  new=c("000", "111"))
```

**Update**: I took @fishtank's basic idea and modified it to fit my more complex use case. My original example had vectors of equal length, but my actual case has a one-to-many relationship between `key` and `old`. This loop works for me.

```
old <- c("test_test.123.test.test", "something.456.something",
         "repeat.456.something")
key <- data.frame(old=c("123", "456"),
                  new=c("000", "111"))
for (i in old) {
  o <- substr(gsub("^[^.]*.", "", i), 1, 3)
  n <- key[key$old==o,]$new
  r <- gsub(o, n, i)
  print(r)
}
#[1] "test_test.000.test.test"
#[1] "something.111.something"
#[1] "repeat.111.something"
```

Comment: Remove the caret and dollar sign. These assert that the pattern starts at the beginning of the string and ends at the end of it.  Also you probably want to use gsub.

Comment: wow, examining all of these good ideas now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapply` with `gsub` using your substitution `key`. You might want to try different regex in `gsub` if your string is more complicated.

```
> key
  old new
1 123 000
2 456 111

> old
[1] "test_test.123.test.test" "something.456.something"

> cbind(old,new=mapply(gsub,key$old,key$new,old))
     old                       new                      
[1,] "test_test.123.test.test" "test_test.000.test.test"
[2,] "something.456.something" "something.111.something"
```

Comment: thanks, @fishtank. i think this is will work for my more complicated use case. one wrinkle though. i have a one-to-many match between `key` and `old`. so a better example of `old` would be: `old <- c("test_test.123.test.test", "something.456.something", "more_more.123")`. your approach throws an error about different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect my regex could be improved but I think this should work

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(old, "\\b[[:digit:]]+\\b", c("000", "111"))
```

One with pure regex, but rather ugly with all the escapes needed in R

```
str_replace_all(old, "\\(?<=\\.\\)\\d+\\(?=\\.\\)", c("000", "111"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern should be `"[[:punct:]][[:digit:]]+[[:punct:]]"` since the `^` and `$` would match the beginning and the end of every element, respectively. Here you have other characters on both ends.

You can also use `"\\.[[:digit:]]+\\."` if you want to `grep` commas and not any punctuation sign instead.

http://regexr.com/ is a nice ressource to ease working with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem?

```
old <- c("test_test.123.test.test", "something.456.something")
key <- c("000", "111")

replace_key <- function(text, key) {
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(text, "([:alpha:]+)\\.\\p{N}*\\.(.+)", 
                                  paste0("$1.", key, ".$2" ))
}

replace_key(old, key)

# [1] "test_test.000.test.test" "something.111.something"
```

make sure to install `stringi`.

Short explanation on the regex:

- `([:alpha:]+)` matches any alphanumeric and keeps it as a variable `$1`
- `\\.` escapes the dot
- `\\p{N}*` matches zero or more of Unicode character class numeric
- `(.+)` matches one or more characters and saves them in `$2`

the `paste` function adds the key that you indicate to want in the future.